# Css fails to apply on a child div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page that I'm creating. When I create a child div inside a parent div, it inherits the background, but when I try to float the child div to the right, it loses the inherited background and turn white. What might I be missing? My fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/njueukavi/Jsj4u/1/)

my  css code is here

```
#fullwidth{
   width: 100%;
   /* background: url(../images/bg.jpg);*/
   background-color: black;
   background-repeat: repeat;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
}

#fullwidth .container{
   width: 994px;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   text-align: left;
   background: transparent;
}

#fullwidth .test{
   float: right;
}
```

my div is here

```
<div id="fullwidth">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="test">
                <ul id='header_nav'>
                    <!--li><img src="images/home-icon.png" /></li-->
                    <li><a href="../design.php">Design</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../designproducts.php">Products</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../events.php">Events</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../eventsservices.php">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../eventsgallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../pr.php">Public Relations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../outdoor.php">Media and Outdoor</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../outdoorservices.php">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../outdoorgallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../production.php">Production</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../productionservices.php">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../productiongallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../login.php">Login</a>
                        <ul>
                            <!--li>Register</li-->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullwidth">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="test">
                <ul id='header_nav'>
                    <!--li><img src="images/home-icon.png" /></li-->
                    <li><a href="../design.php">Design</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../designproducts.php">Products</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../events.php">Events</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../eventsservices.php">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../eventsgallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../pr.php">Public Relations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../outdoor.php">Media and Outdoor</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../outdoorservices.php">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../outdoorgallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../production.php">Production</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../productionservices.php">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../productiongallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../login.php">Login</a>
                        <ul>
                            <!--li>Register</li-->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cler"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**Css**

```
.cler{
    clear:both;
}
```

on your last div child end

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jsj4u/8/)**

---

**----------
2nd option is**

write this css

```
#fullwidth:after{
content:'';
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table;
}
```

**[Demo-2](http://jsfiddle.net/Jsj4u/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
it loses the inherited background and turn white
```

It doesn't fail, it's just floating so you just need to clear the float after the `div` with class `test`.

Here is a good article about it http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html